# Screen blinks/flashes while switching monitor due to KVM + DP

Tags: windows, display, displayport, kvm-switch

This will be a long story because I need top share all observations in case any of it is relevant.

My monitor has a direct DP connection to my PC (for high refresh rate) and an HDMI connection to an HDMI-KVM which then leads to my PC and my consoles. The sound goes via the KVM and is extracted from the HDMI signal to go to my amp.

The issue I have is when the KVM is set to connect to my PC (otherwise I have no sound) and the monitor then has 2 active incoming connections.
When I switch on my monitor, it shows the DP connection. Three seconds later it does a quick blink of "black, image, black, image", then pauses a second and does it once more.
For some reason this also breaks the night light functionality in windows. It's warm in the beginning and cold after finishing all the flashing, even though it's still "enabled".

This did not happen from the start when I had this setup. After a major windows update, it suddenly started happening. It lasted for about a year and then with another windows update it was suddenly resolved. I did not update my Nvidia drivers at that time.
Now tonight I had another small windows update and I also updated my Nvidia drivers and the issue came back. I checked windows update which had the big 20H2 available so I installed that but no change. No more updates are available.

A few observations:

- If I switch off my KVM, the issue goes away.
- If I unplug the hdmi cable from my monitor, the issue persists but only does the "black, image, black, image" **once**.
- If I unplug the DP cable, it takes a few seconds (black screen) to detect the hdmi input and then shows it without any further flashing as described above.

I **think** this means that the following happens:

- Switch monitor on
- Monitor detects DP immediately and shows it
- The KVM is a bit slow in general and a few seconds later it connects the monitor with the PC via HDMI.
- HDMI has some protocol to make monitors detect it and so the monitor switches (first blinking)
- DP is higher prio than HDMI so it switches back. (second blinking)

However, seeing as it did not do this for almost a year, this makes me suspect that it is not the monitor but something in windows.

My conclusion is that it is the windows update in which they broke it again but last time it took a year for them to fix it and I really don't want to wait that long again (especially with it breaking night light which I can only fix by restarting explorer manually).

And by the way, I have night light on permanently. I tried a program called Lightbulb which works well as a replacement but the blinking also causes that to stop "warming" the screen even though it's still enabled. If I disable and enable it again then it's back to normal.

I also want to point out than the DP connection never flickers (freesync issue) and that the blinking never happens again after the monitor has switched on (bad cable). So please don't suggest those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by performing a clean install of the nvidia drivers (normal reinstall won't cut it). Unfortunately that also resets all the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread, but since I also had this problem, I wanted to add that there was a recent fix in the NVIDIA drivers 535.98 - WHQL from Tue May 30, 2023 that could affect this (and apparantely did solve that problem for me):

https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/results/205305/

In the "Release Highlights", below "Fixed General Bugs", it says:

"Monitor may briefly flicker on waking from display sleep if DSR/DLDSR is enabled. [3592260]"

It seems that I was affected by this bug, even if I did (of course) not use DSR/DLDSR in desktop mode (but it was configured and available). After installing the NVIDIA drivers 535.98, the problem is gone for me.

So if anyone has an NVIDIA GPU and is facing a similar problem, try updating your drivers to at least version 535.98 and see if that helps!

Getting it solved by doing a clean install also indicates it could have been that very same issue, btw. (because a clean install will delete the DSR/DLDSR settings).